# Flutter - Having trouble loading this profile image from Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I hope all is well with you. I have another issue with flutter. I'm trying to get this profile image to load from a review object (Code down below). I tried renaming and reloading the firebase storage and everything. I tried adding async and await with no avail. If you would like to see the tutorial that I am following, I have included a link down below. I really appreciate the help!

Tutorial Link: https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-android-masterclass-build-3-apps-with-google-flutter/

Episode: 113

Image of my screen:
[image: replace image of momo is here with picture.]

list_widgets -> _ReviewListTileState -> initState()

```
@override
 void initState() {
   this._review = widget.review;
   this._review.contact.getContactInfoFromFirestore().whenComplete(() {
    setState(()  {
      print("Dot Dots");
    });
   });
   super.initState();
 }
```

list_widgets -> _ReviewListTileState -> build()

```
InkResponse(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => view_profile_page(contact: _review.contact),
                  ),
                );
                },
              child: Container(
                child: (_review.contact.displayImage == null) ? Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 7.5,
                  child: Text("${_review.contact.firstName} was here"),
                ) : CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: _review.contact.displayImage,
                  radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

review_objects -> Review{}

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutterrentalapp/Models/user_objects.dart';

class Review{

  Contact contact;
  String text;
  double rating;
  DateTime dateTime;

  Review();

  void createReview(Contact contact, String text, double rating, DateTime dateTime){
    this.contact = contact;
    this.text = text;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
  }

  void getReviewInfoFromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    this.rating = snapshot['rating'].toDouble() ?? 2.5;
    this.text = snapshot['text'] ?? "";

    Timestamp timestamp = snapshot['dateTime'] ?? Timestamp.now();
    this.dateTime = timestamp.toDate();

    String fullName = snapshot['name'] ?? "";
    String contactID = snapshot['userID'] ?? "";
    _loadContactInfo(contactID,fullName);
  }

  void _loadContactInfo(String id, String fullName){
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0];
    lastName = fullName.split(" ")[1];
    this.contact = Contact(id: id, firstName: firstName, lastName:lastName);

  }

}
```

Comment: Is your profile picture loaded to firebase storage? are you able to see this on a bucket and validate that the image exists and is not corrupted?

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

   are you receiving any error message on app debug console?

Comment: Yessir, I can view it in bucket and everything. turned on my VPN because I couldn't view any pictures from any aspect of the application or on drive. I replaced the image multiple times and even attempted to rename the image.

Answer (score 1):

Another one of these issues where the classic programmer had a mistype. I had to go back over the code within one of the classes and make a slight change. It's been too far gone though for me to find it.

Thank you all for the helpful suggestions.